# No matches for kind"gateway" and "virtualservice"

Tags: kubernetes, istio, docker-desktop

I am using Docker Desktop version 3.6.0 which has Kubernetes 1.21.3.

I am following this tutorial to get started on Istio

https://istio.io/latest/docs/setup/getting-started/

Istio is properly installed as per the instructions.

Now whenever i try to apply the Istio configuration

by issuing the command `kubectl apply -f samples/bookinfo/networking/bookinfo-gateway.yaml`.

I get the following error

```
unable to recognize "samples/bookinfo/networking/bookinfo-gateway.yaml": no matches for kind "Gateway" in version "networking.istio.io/v1alpha3"
unable to recognize "samples/bookinfo/networking/bookinfo-gateway.yaml": no matches for kind "VirtualService" in version "networking.istio.io/v1alpha3"
```

I checked in internet and found that the Gateway and VirtualService resources are missing.

If i perform `kubectl get crd` i get no resources found

Content of bookinfo-gatway.yaml

```
    apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: bookinfo-gateway
spec:
  selector:
    istio: ingressgateway # use istio default controller
  servers:
  - port:
      number: 80
      name: http
      protocol: HTTP
    hosts:
    - "*"
---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: bookinfo
spec:
  hosts:
  - "*"
  gateways:
  - bookinfo-gateway
  http:
  - match:
    - uri:
        exact: /productpage
    - uri:
        prefix: /static
    - uri:
        exact: /login
    - uri:
        exact: /logout
    - uri:
        prefix: /api/v1/products
    route:
    - destination:
        host: productpage
        port:
          number: 9080
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The CRDs for istio should be installed as part of the istioctl install process, I'd recommend re-running the install if you don't have them available.

```
>>> ~/.istioctl/bin/istioctl install --set profile=demo -y
✔ Istio core installed
✔ Istiod installed
✔ Egress gateways installed
✔ Ingress gateways installed
✔ Installation complete
```

kubectl get po -n istio-system should look like

```
>>> kubectl get po -n istio-system
NAME                                   READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
istio-egressgateway-7ddb45fcdf-ctnp5   1/1     Running   0          3m20s
istio-ingressgateway-f7cdcd7dc-zdqhg   1/1     Running   0          3m20s
istiod-788ff675dd-9p75l                1/1     Running   0          3m32s
```

Otherwise your initial install has gone wrong somewhere.

Comment: It was a problem with my istio installation...thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can apply CRD to your cluster without using `istioctl install` from https://github.com/istio/istio/blob/master/manifests/charts/base/crds/crd-all.gen.yaml
with

```
kubectl apply -f ./crd-all.gen.yaml
```